# Django with a SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, django

I am looking into developing a new user registration system for my company. In the past we have made use of ASP.net for all web development.

Due to the huge charge associated with this I am looking at moving towards a more open source alternative. The issue at the moment is that the db we have is SQL Server and we have no way of changing this in the forth coming future.

Has anyone any experience of building a django application with SQL Server backend for the database?

I would most like to hear of any issues you may have faced.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like there's some decent resources out there:

http://code.google.com/p/django-mssql/

http://code.google.com/p/django-pyodbc/

https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/DjangoOnWindowsWithIISAndSQLServer

I personally don't have experience with it, and the backporting of your models from db->code could possibly be a painful step. Also, it seems like most of these packages want to work with sqlserver 2000 or 2005, so hopefully you are not using 2008.